# Referencing store config values in phtml templates

Tags: phtml

I am attempting to modify the frontend output for Print Invoice/Print Order to comply with ATO requirements.

The template in question is `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/print.phtml`

I need to display two fields from the store configuration in the page header, the paths are:

```
'general/store_information/phone'and'fontis_australia/business/abn'
```

Both paths are defined and work correctly in transactional emails using markup tags, but in this script I always get null when using `getStoreConfig().`

```
<?php echo $this->__('Tel') ?><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone')) ?><br>
<?php echo $this->__('ABN') ?><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getStoreConfig('fontis_australia/business/abn')) ?>
```

I have tried a few variations of these 2 lines, but I am new to both magento and php so i would appreciate any help I can get.

thanks
Tom

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try `Mage::getStoreConfig` instead of `$this->getStoreConfig`

Comment: Good thought.  That works perfectly

Comment: Great. Please upvote or accept as answer if you find it useful